# NavigationView goes blank with repeated transition from detail view from navigation link

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

**Background:**
Hi everyone I am developing an app on SwiftUI I have a navigation view and a detail view but Navigation View bar was pushing my view down so I had added:

```
} // Navigation view closure
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .hiddenNavigationBarStyle()
```

and this is what's behind the above:

```
struct HiddenNavigationBar: ViewModifier {
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

}

```
extension View {
func hiddenNavigationBarStyle() -> some View {
    modifier( HiddenNavigationBar() )
}
```

}

so this got rid of navigation bar and the back button (and the pushing down of the view) but to allow the user to be able to navigate back, I added a navigation link to my detail view to serve as a back button.

**Problem**: When I switch back and forth repeatedly from detail view to the main view, around the 5th time or so, the main view suddenly goes blank (not crashing). I was able to repro on a number of devices.

The reason I put in *that* code excerpt is because, when I take that out and the nav bar isn't hidden, when I tap through the standard back button, the problem doesn't occur, so I narrowed it down to that.

**Additional info:**
The issue has been reported [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126121) and people wrote that it's been resolved, maybe mine creates an edge case because of the hidden navigation bar?

**Question:**
Any thoughts on why this could be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Either:

1. a solution to avoid the screen going blank or,
2. an alternative to the hidden navigation bar style that stops the UI from being pushed down :)

Thank you so much!